# How To test OSGi SOAP bundle in PAX-EXAM?

Tags: osgi-bundle, pax-exam, pax-web

I am able to test normal bundle using PAX-EXAM but I can't for OSGi SOAP bunlde, it throws error before activating OSGi SOAP bundle:

```
biz.vnc.commons.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Header not found by abc-zimbra-soap [57]
    at biz.vnc.commons.ws.SOAPServiceInitializer.<init>(SOAPServiceInitializer.java:139)
    at biz.vnc.zimbrainstance.UserZimbraInstance.<init>(UserZimbraInstance.java:201)
    at biz.vnc.zimbrainstance.ZimbraInstance.<init>(ZimbraInstance.java:20)
    at biz.vnc.mw.zimbra.Zimbra.activate(Zimbra.java:51)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Header not found by vnc-zimbra-soap [57]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

I'm using PAX-EXAM, is there any other way to test SOAP OSGi bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it by adding this property in PAX test configuration:

bootDelegationPackages("sun.*","com.sun.*")